# starting activities without .class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have searched for how to start and Activity from another Activity and I keep finding

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExampleClass.class);
startActivity(intent);

But I want to start from an instantiated activity. I have a container with many activities and when the user selects from my UI I wish to show a particular one.

So, for example.

```
class MyExample extends Activity {

MyExample mx = new MyExample();
```

So how do I now start this Activity.

What I would like is

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, mx);
startActivity(intent);
```

Any help greatly appreciated from a reasonably experienced Java developer but new to Android.

Comment: What is the reason for doing this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to show a particular Activity from a number of Activities, when the user swipes to the left or right I wish to launch a new Activity that already exists as a instantiated class

Comment: No, I mean what is the purpose of launching an "instantiated" activity? The reason for you can't use Intent intent = new Intent(this, ExampleClass.class); startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible, though I do not understand yet why you want to do this.

Make sure the `Activity` you want to startis well declared in your manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".com.example.MyExample" ... />
```

Then you can call in you current Activity :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyExample")); 
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: This shows how new I am to Android development, I'm happy to do this but please advise how. I've looked around the page but can't find the 'This answered my question' part.

Comment: @user2244131 The best advice for you is ever and never do this unless you have a very strong reason for doing this because this is completely beyond Android Development Standards